# How to use Git commands without human interaction?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have a remote machine with a program which downloads some source codes from some repos using a only-read svn user for that program. Now is working with svn without human interaction doing thinks like this:

Doing checkouts:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn checkout --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username "+Constants.svnUser+" --password "+Constants.svnPassword+" "+repositoryURL+" ." , null , dir);
```

Updating code:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn update --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username "+Constants.svnUser+" --password "+Constants.svnPassword+" ", null , dir);
```

It works perfectly, but now I'm trying to download source code from Git repositories using a read only Git user, and I can't find the way to do the same non interactive behaviour with Git.

Given a Git repo, a git user and a git password, how to init Git and clone, checkout or pull source code without human interaction?

I can't find any info about how to achieve that give these three items.

Answer (score 7):

From git v2.3.0, you can set the environment variable `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0` to avoid your script to hang on the git command expecting manual authentication.

**Example:**

```
$ GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://git.example.com/my/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.example.com': terminal prompts disabled
$ echo $?
128
```

**Source:** [man 1 git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTERMINALPROMPTcode)

Answer (score 2):

I often use `--no-pager` flag, for example to directly output the `diff` in terminal:

```
$ git --no-pager diff
```

Comment: if you redirect the command output to a file, it sets "no-pager" automatically I suppose