# Too many tags so `git tag` will stop with a colon for further input

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a repo with too many tags so when I run `git tag` it will stop with a colon for further input. My purpose is to write a script (shell or python) to delete all the tags less than a specific version number, say `v8.x`.

But as the command stops for the further input, how to I make it continue to run? Do I have to resort to expect(of pexpect) to make it work?

I found this [How to use git commands without human interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745520/how-to-use-git-commands-without-human-interaction) but it didn't solve my question.

---- update ----

From VonC's answer and comment I learned [Git-Config: core.pager](https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/git-config-core-pager-807e17d64243) but then I also found I can use `git show-ref --tags` (or better `git show-ref --abbrev=7 --tags`) to get what I need. I found `git show-ref` seems not use pager because it outputs all the tags at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of `git -c pager.tag=false tag`, you can add a filter by pattern with [the `--list` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--l) (you can add [sorting options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309))

```bash
# Windows:
git -c pager.tag=false tag -l "v8.[0123467].*"
# or
git --no-pager tag -l "v8.[0123467].*"

----

# Linux:
git -c pager.tag=false tag -l 'v8.[0123467].*'
# or
git --no-pager tag -l 'v8.[0123467].*'
```

The OP also suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309) the use of [`git show-ref --abbrev=7 --tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309), a [plumbing (so, non-porcelain) command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309) which is not affected by pager.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I didn't know the pager concept so can you further explain it ? BTW, according to the suggested question I run `git --no-pager tag` to get the result, so what is difference between `--no-pager` and `pager.tag=false` ?

Comment: @Qiulang You can see more about [pager here](https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/git-config-core-pager-807e17d64243). `--no-pager` is an alias for `pager.tag=false`.

Comment: Thanks! BTW in my case it is `git --no-pager tag -l "v[123467].*"`

Comment: @Qiulang "less than a specific version", got it. I have edited the answer accordingly. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I also found I can use `git show-ref --tags` to get what I need and that command seems not use pager at all, so I may argue that pager is not used consistently.

Comment: @Qiulang Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I suspect git show-ref is a plumbing command, not a porcelain one. As such, it is not affected by pager, since it is supposed to be used in script (while porcelain commands are used by actual user, hence the pager).

Comment: Hi a typo `git show-ref` not `git show-raf`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Qiulang Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.