# How to get GIT and/or SSH to gracefully fail and not ask for password authentication on key or other failure

Tags: git, ssh

I am writing a build script that can optionally clone a repository and I want it to only do so when the current user is a valid user for access to a git repository ( ie: can log into private git hosting account with a valid ssh key, and not have it ask for a password and wait )

So the build script will just issue a warning message to the console and NOT clone or build that private part the user can't access.

I can try to ssh first to detect if the user:host is a valid one first but would also not want it to ask and wait for a user or password when attempting to connect but to fail in this case in a way I can detect in a script. ( stderr or stdout output )  specify using a key only ?

Comment: I just learned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943991/10875738) exists to make git non-interactive (and fail instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ssh -nT <host>` to test the SSH connection to your server. Just this, of course, will prompt for a password.

- `-T` disables tty allocation, so it just throws you into a raw connection
- `-n` disables stdin, so that you really do not interact with the host.

You can disable password authentication with `-o PasswordAuthentication=no`. Full command would be:

```bash
ssh -nT -o PasswordAuthentication=no <host>
```

You'd then proceed to check the exit code of this. If you want to to not print anything to stdout, you can add `-q` (quiet mode).

All of this requires that the user has a working ssh connection set up (and the according `.ssh/config` file). Afaik, there is no way to accept pre-configured passwords but not have the interactive password prompt show.

[[ssh docs](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh)] [[related askUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419546/ssh-never-ask-for-a-password)]

Comment: cool - will try - this would only be for using keys.  But hopefully work if no key is present and no password provided.

Comment: If no key is present and password is ignored, ssh -T will definitely fail.

Answer (score 1):

To test your ssh connection without user intervention, you could try
`BatchMode`. When set, password authentication is disabled. See ssh_config(5)
for details.  The `-E` option allows for an error log. Use `/dev/null` to
ignore. Send a bash noop command, `:`, to run if the connection succeeds.

```bash
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -E /dev/null user@example.com : && \
    echo 'good to go' || echo 'failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your C:\Users<uname>.ssh folder you can create a file named "config" and add the below content and save.

```
PreferredAuthentications publickey
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Next time when you try accessing repos for which you lack access it ll fail gracefully.

Comment: not applicable.  This so someone who downloiads a module from git hub that has a setup script that will set up only the item the user is authorized to get and should not require any significant configuration   before running the setup.