Hide all output of `git ls-remote`
I am writing a function to check, given an http/https URL whether the URL corresponds to an existing git repo or not. I want to hide the output coming from git ls-remote. Any idea how to do that?
import subprocess

def check_git(url: str) -> bool:
    try:
        ret = subprocess.run(
            ["git", "ls-remote", "-q", "--exit-code", url, "HEAD"],
            check=True,
            timeout=10,
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
        if ret.returncode != 0:
            return False
        return True
    except (subprocess.TimeoutExpired, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
        return False

if not check_git("https://github.com/ghost/bar.git"):
    print("\nCould not find repo")

When I run this, I get a username prompt. So it seems that subprocess redirection is not working here.
python git.py
Username for 'https://github.com':
Could not find repo


You're only redirecting stdout to null.  Stderr is still going to your terminal.  I do have two notes.  First, there is a Python module to manipulate git directly.  Second, "valid" checks like this are almost never worth the trouble.  There are far too many corner conditions to check.  If the user gets the name wrong, they'll find out very quickly.

@TimRoberts stderr is going to subprocess.STDOUT which gets redirected to devnull so stdout and stderr here are combined.

"[...] whether the url corresponds to an existing git repo or not" did you mean git remote instead of git repo?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943991/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/34396983/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+disable+password+prompt

It seems using start_new_session=True is the solution:
import subprocess

def check_git(url: str) -> bool:
    try:
       subprocess.check_call(
            ["git", "ls-remote", "-q", "--exit-code", url, "HEAD"],
            timeout=10,
            start_new_session=True,
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
        return True
    except (subprocess.TimeoutExpired, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
        return False

if not check_git("https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell.git"):
    print("Could not find repo")
else:
    print("Valid repo")


You still want stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL if that's what you actually mean. Your current code redirects stederr to the original stdout.
